# Trying to prove (A ∩ B) - C = (A - C) ∩ (B - C)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Trying to prove $(A ∩ B) - C = (A - C) ∩ (B - C)$ Im stuck here on this problem:

$(A ∩ B) - C = \{x\mid x \in (A ∩ B) ∧ x \not\in C\}$

$(A ∩ B) - C = \{x\mid(x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ B) ∧ x ∉ C\}$

$(A ∩ B) - C = \{x\mid(x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ C) \lor (x ∈ B ∧ x ∉ C\}$

I'm stuck right about here because how do I change the or ($\wedge$) sign to the intersection sign ($\cap$).

Edit: step 3, changed the and to an or

Comment: Why did you put an "or" in the last line? You only have "and"'s

Comment: $\land$ isn't "or". It's "and". And $\lor$ isn't "and". It's "or". You shouldn't have any "or"s. they should all be "and"s. And it should be easy to the point of being obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in A\cap B-C$. Then $x \in A$, $x \in B$ $x \notin C$. So $x \in A \wedge x \notin C$ and $ x \in B \wedge x \notin C$ so $x \in (A-C) \cap (B-C)$. So we have $A \cap B -C\subset (A-C) \cap (B-C)$.
Conversely suppose $x \in (A-C) \cap (B-C)$. Then $ x \in A \wedge x\notin  C $ and $ x \in B \wedge x \notin C $ so $ x \in A \cap B -C$ and the equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

There is some property that determines membership for each  A, B, and C. Call these a, b, and c respectively. x is in LHS iff (a(x) and b(x)) and not c(x) iff (a(x) and not c(x)) and (b(x) and not c(x)) iff x is in RHS.

Answer (score 0):

You can complete it as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
(A \cap B) - C
&=& \{x\mid(x \in A \wedge x \not\in C) \wedge (x \in B \wedge x \not\in C)\}\\
&=& \{x\mid(x \in (A - C)) \wedge (x \in (B - C))\}\\
&=& \{x\mid x \in (A - C) \cap (B - C)\}\\
&=& (A - C) \cap (B - C)
\end{eqnarray}